# How to delete specific columns from a .xlsx generated by a sheetJs script from an HTML table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xlsx, sheetjs

I generate an .XLSX from an HTML table with SheetJS. The table has 18 cols but I only need 14, I am trying to delete or hide the last four but it didn't work .

I use this code:

```
name = 'ExcelEscenariosOptimizacion.xlsx';
  exportToExcel(): void {
    let element = document.getElementById('tabla-escenarios-optimizacion');

    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element);

I tried this but it doesn't work
    worksheet['!cols'] =[]; 
   // worksheet['!cols'] [29] = {hidden: true};
I used this to hide some cols but it didn't work  with the last 
    // worksheet['!cols'] [17] = {hidden: true};
    // worksheet['!cols'] [16] = {hidden: true};
    // worksheet['!cols'] [15] = {hidden: true};
    // worksheet['!cols'] [14] = {hidden: true};
 
I use this ro get bigger the cells
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 15});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 25});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 20});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 20});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 25});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 15});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 20});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 25});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 15});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 20});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 35});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 35});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 35});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 30});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 30});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 20});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 25});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 25});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 25});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 25});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 25});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 40});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 35});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 30});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 40});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 30});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 30});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 30});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 30});
    worksheet['!cols'].push({ width: 30});

    const book: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

  
Here I am trying to delete the last four cols
s: is for start col, e: is for the end col.
c: column
r: row.
    var range = { s: { c: 0, r: 0 }, e: { c: 900, r: 10 } };//A1:A5
    var dataRange = [];
    /* Iterate through each element in the structure */
    for (var R = range.s.r; R <= range.e.r; ++R) {
      for (var C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
        var cell_address = { c: C, r: R };
        var data = XLSX.utils.encode_cell(cell_address);
        dataRange.push(worksheet[data]);
      }
    }

    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(book, worksheet, 'Sheet1');

    XLSX.writeFile(book, this.name);
  }
```

I do not know how can I use, I reviewed the documentation https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/csf/general but I can't.